# Como usar boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

soy nuevo en esto y quisiera saber como puedo usar boostrap en html, llevo pocas horas estudiándolo
https://getbootstrap.com/ dejo la URL de la página

Comment: Bienvenido Alexander a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: la página que colocaste justo tiene una guía introductoria solo basta con buscar un poco, incluso contiene ejemplos sencillos de cada una de sus estilos y componentes. Sí tienes una duda más especifica, entonces si podrías formular una pregunta aquí, en otro caso, no entra dentro de la tematica de este sitio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que tienes que hacer es entrar a la págian de BOOTSTRAP, luego de esto tienes que consumirlo desde el HEAD, antes de poner tus estilos, para que tus estilos pisen los estilos de Bootstrap.
Usa ésta URL.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Tus estilos-->
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hola Mundo.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes ir al link de documentación y leer como incluirlo en tu página web

En la misma página de bootstrap tienes una plantilla para que puedas partir sobre ella.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Para más información consulta la documentación en la página de bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/